# YouTube blocking videos

Tags: youtube

I have seen lots of people uploaidng complete shows, movies which they don't own. However, when i do so, YouTube blocks it. It does give me an option that i can dispute the objections but then it gives me bundle of options

My question is how to upload such videos? In the dispute section, what should i select. I know its not my work, its not original work but i am uploading just like others. Can i ?

Comment: So, you're asking us to help you break the law, or at least YouTube's terms of service?

Comment: If you believe what you're doing comes under the "fair use" provision, then perhaps this will be helpful to you: [Web video sharing service with "fair use" protection?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/6445)

Answer (score 1):

These others have somehow slipped through YouTube's checking. What you are looking to do is not only against YouTube's terms of service but illegal. I would suggest that you do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to post something that isn't yours on YouTube like a show you would need to follow the fair use laws.

If you were to not follow fair use it wouldn't just be against YouTube but also it is illegal.

But if you use small clips of movies or tv shows and you use it to make a new form of content, like a reaction, then that would be fair use.
Also if you use the clip just mention that it is not yours (again if it a small clip), and make it to where it is your own.
Some do parodies of small clips from shows to be considered fair use, but it is not an exact law and you just have to be careful.

But regarding posting full tv-shows, and movies on YouTube is not possible. And the ones who do is just temporary until YouTube finds that it is copyrighted material and not fair use.